# Moved our web application server to a new machine with a new IP address, but some clients seem to have cached the old one

Tags: windows, iis, ip-address

We moved our web application server (Windows & IIS) to a new machine with a new IP address. Updated all the DNS records to points correctly at the new server, and have ensured they have propagated properly.

Everything seems fine for the majority, but some of our clients seem to have our old IP address cached somewhere as they are still landing on the old server (which currently just has an notice stating that our service is unavailable until we decommission it).

I know you can use HTTP response codes to tell people that a site has moved to a new URL, is there something similar that can be done to tell them that the resolved IP address has changed?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. Even if the reason was minor, it might help someone in the future (and the question won't be "unanswered").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problem was my own stupidity/forgetfulness. As it happens we own two domains that our DNS points at our server. One of them is our old URL and is only used by very old clients that have saved shortcuts to it somewhere. Ultimately I forgot to update the DNS records for the old domain so it continued to direct traffic to our old server, which is why only a subset of our (oldest) clients were effected.

If you find your self here, just check if you have any other domains whose DNS records also need updating before you go any deeper! Then check out @Larryc's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/978896/139279) for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell them that the site has moved, but their machine will still go to the wrong address. You need to find out where they are getting the old address and clear it.

You can run 'nslookup' and verify the address their dns is coming up with, at the same time you can also verify they are using the correct dns server.

If you think they are getting it from cache then run  'ipconfig /flushdns'.

Or it could be hard coded in the host file.

If you are using WINS then  it could be in the lmhosts file.

But you need to find out where it is coming from and squash it.

EDIT: Another thought, they could be clicking on a shortcut and that shortcut could have the address hard coded in it.

Comment: The problem was my own stupidity, so I am going to delete the question. I apologise if this robs you of the upvote I gave you, thank you for taking the time to answer me anyway. Basically we had an old URL that was also pointing at our server that some clients were still using and I forgot to update it's DNS records with the new IP address.

Comment: @Ben I think you should leave this here. If Larryc could update his answer to check for other urls pointing to the old IP too, this would still be a great and informative Question & Answer

Comment: @Ben That's great, I didn't hit upon the final solution, but at least it got you to thinking in the right direction. Smock Thx, but I wasn't the one who thought of the URL's, Ben did. I can't take credit for it. But anyone reading this question will hopefully check the comments as well.

Comment: This is the nicest exchange I've witnessed on a stackedexchange site! I'll clean up my question and add an answer